# How to load Flutter dropdown button based on json query?

Tags: json, dart, flutter, dropdown

In my flutter app I need to create 3 dropdown button. I have local Json file that has list of companies in different countries.

**Queries:**

1. First dropdown button loads the company names (**bAd**).
2. Second dropdown button loads the company branches (**sAd**)that is selected in First dropdown button
3. Third dropdown button loads the **sIlKd** code that is selected in Second dropdown button.

I know how to load the local json. Also I know how to make the dropdown button. But I don’t know how to loads all 3 dropdown button based on the 3 query that I try to explained in above.

**How to load Flutter dropdown button based on son query?**

```
    {
   "companiesList":{
      "companyBranch":[
         {
            "company":{
               "bKd":"0001",
               "bAd":"Comany_A",
               "bIlAd":"England"
            },
            "branches":[
               {
                  "bKd":"0001",
                  "sKd":"00001",
                  "sAd":"London",
                  "sIlKd":"006"
               },
               ......
            ]
         },
         {
            "company":{
               "bKd":"0004",
               "bAd":"company_B",
               "bIlAd":"Germany"
            },
            "branches":[
               {
                  "bKd":"0004",
                  "sKd":"90001",
                  "sAd":"Berlin",
                  "sIlKd":"999"
               },
               ......
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In initState I call future to load json and than I use another future to load items as shown below. And I use **itemsComanyNames** to load dropdown.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool _autoValidate = false;
  bool jsonLoad = false;
  List<Map> _myCompanies;
  String _myCompany;

  // TODO: (1) - initState
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadJson();
  }

  Future loadJson() async {
    String jsonAccount = await rootBundle
        .loadString("packages/niyazi_fixdropdown/company.json");
    setState(() {
      _myCompanies = List<Map>.from(jsonDecode(jsonAccount) as List);
      jsonLoad = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return jsonLoad != true
        ? new Scaffold(body: new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()))
        : new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: new SafeArea(
                top: false,
                bottom: false,
                child: new Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                    child: new ListView(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new FormField<String>(
                          builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                            return new DropdownButton(
                                value: _myCompany,
                                isDense: false,
                                items: _myCompanies((c) {
                                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value:
                                        "${c["bAd"].toString()}",
                                    child: new Text(
                                      "${c["bAd"].toString()}",
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      softWrap: true,
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                hint: new Text(“Choose a Company…”,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    softWrap: true,
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      color: Colors.red.shade700,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    )),
                                onChanged: (String value) {
                                  // ???????????
                                  // ???????????
                                });
                          },
                        ),
                        new Container(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 20.0),
                            child: new RaisedButton(
                              child: const Text('Submit'),
                              onPressed: null,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ))),
          );
  }
}
```

**Update-1:** I am getting error on _myCompanies.map((c) line as **NoSuchMethodError**: The method 'map' was called on null.

**Update-2: new error:** _InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast on _myCompanies = List.from(jsonDecode(jsonAccount) as List); line

Comment: You could put the 3 `DropdownButton`s inside a StatefulWidget: based on user choices, dynamically regenerate each `DropdownButton`'s options. Load the JSON to start, populate dropdown #1, then track choices with `onChanged` listeners to update Widget state. `.map` & `.filter` are useful to regenerate lists based on choices. Something like `DATA.map(branch => branch.company.bAd)` for #1, `DATA.filter(branch => branch.company.bAd == <selected company from #1>).map(e => e.branches)`, for #2 and then `.map` out the sIlKd from the branches list #2 for #3. Give it a try & post if you get stuck!

Comment: thmsdnnr, I keep getting The method 'map' was called on null. I update my question and add loadjson method, any idea why?

Comment: Do you initialize `_myCompanies` in your Widget state? I'd initialize `_myCompanies` with an empty List, & make `loadEverything()` call `setState` to update the value of `_myCompanies` after it loads the json. Also, `loadItems()` is not an async function: it just consumes data *from* an async function. You can drop the async and call it in your Build method for the Widget. Initially it generates an empty list of dropdown items, and then when the json loads and the state updates, it populates with the new values. You can use the same technique to update dropdown lists when user makes choices.

Comment: but I need to use CircularProgressIndicator until I can load everything

Comment: You could do a check in Build: if `_myCompanies` is empty, render CircularProgressIndicator; otherwise, generate the DropdownMenuItems choices and render the dropdowns.

Comment: I update my full code and new error is: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: So how to edit DATA.map(branch => branch.company.bAd) and where?

Comment: Hey @Nick, I'd be happy to continue this in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183824/room-for-thmsdnnr-and-nick ... I think the comments thread is not going to be the best way to help debug.

Comment: thanks I am in chat now

Comment: thanks. This post help me a lot. Also doing 3 dropdown button.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting an error `_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'List'` is because you're trying to assign a Map to a List. What you can do here is map the JSON response to an object similar to what has been demonstrated on this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#create-an-album-class).